# why my calculator shows $10\%9=0.9$

Tags: arithmetic

When I search in Google it shows me correct result [$10\%9=1$](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Mma0iNtwnGZFVHZ0FHQmFiakE/view?usp=drivesdk)

But in my calculator I get [$10\%9=0.9$](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Mma0iNtwnGTXd6bDhCcTQ5R3M/view?usp=drivesdk)

Let me know the reason soon and  if you have great solution that would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your calculator may be interpreting % as "take the number after it, then convert it to a percentage", and then 10%9 is presumably "10 times 9 percent" which is indeed 0.9.

Comment: Short answer: `%` means different things to google and to a calculator.

Comment: then which simpol i should choose in my calculator to find modulas

Comment: The meaning google (apparently) assigns to `%` is a function seldom found on calcuators.

Comment: Some graphing calculators have a function `remainder` that you can give two arguments, in this case, `remainder(10,9)` would result in `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google (as well as a bunch of programming languages) interprets `10%9` as $10\mod 9$ and thus results in $1$.

`a%n`, or $a\mod n$, will have google find the $0\leq r<n$ such that there is an integer $k$ such that $kn+r=a$ (which is different than the usual $\text{mod}$, since those define equivalence classes, yet very similar).

---

Your calculator however assumes with `a%n` you mean "$a$ times $n$ percent" and will thus result in $a\cdot \frac{n}{100}$.

Answer (score 1):

To compute $a\%n$ the way Google does, i.e. interpreting it as $a\mod n$, we can use the following formula:

$$a\%n=a\mod n=a - \left(\left\lfloor\frac an\right\rfloor \times n\right)$$

That is to say:

1. Compute $\frac an$
2. Round it down to the nearest integer
3. Multipy it by $n$
4. Subtract the result from the original $a$

For your example we would do:

\begin{align}10\%9&=10-\left(\left\lfloor\frac {10}{9}\right\rfloor \times 9\right)\\
&=10-\left(\left\lfloor1.\overline{111}\right\rfloor\times 9\right)\tag{Step $1$}\\
&=10-\left(1\times 9\right)\tag{Step $2$}\\
&=10-9\tag{Step $3$}\\
&=1\tag{Step $4$}\end{align}